# Selenium IDE - Trying to verify Table headings with its value

Tags: firefox, automated-tests, selenium-ide

For viewing the table, below is the attached image:
[image]

Using selenium IDE- I am looking for a way to verify the table heading with its values in the table as shown in image. There are 6 columns in the table and I am looking to verify each column heading and the data within it.

So, say, I am looking for Column Heading = "File Name" and data like File Name = "Datasheet 1.xlsx" file, which could exist in any row 1 to 100.

I think I should use `Command: VerifyTable`, but I am having trouble on the syntax. In the reference it shows the xpath locator as the example:
`xpath=//table[@id='studentDataUploadHistoryTable']/thead/tr/th[3]`.

This is the source code that i m using to verify my table:

```
<tr>
<td>verifyTable</td>
<td>//table[@id='studentDataUploadHistoryTable']/thead/tr/th[3]</td>
<td>File Name</td>
</tr>
```

How could I verify Column headings with data within it? Please post your HTML-Code for my table so that i can verify the table headings and the table contents.

Thanks,